# Alignment of two divs side by side and horizontally same

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to align two `<div>`s side by side and also align them in the same line. One contains a checkbox which is changed in to toggle button using CSS and other has plain text. The problem is when I tried to make them side by side their content is not aligned properly vertically. The toggle button is higher then the text in the second `<div>`.

Here is my code:

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 47px;
  height: 25px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left;">
  <div style="float: left;">
    <p id="show_crash_toggle_text" style="font-size:20px;" <b>User</b>&emsp;</p>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left: 60px;">
    <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" onclick = "show_crash_log()">
          <span class="slider"></span>
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:150px;">
  <b style="font-size:20px">Search by: </b>
</div>
```

Here are some images that show the problem.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try display:inline

Comment: you could use flexbox for that

Comment: refer this - https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: @SPlatten :- display:inline is also not working. I did this <div style="margin-left:150px;display:inline"> for second div. or am i missing something?

Comment: from what i can see, there is default margin to p tag removing that might work

Comment: @ShubhankGupta, for display:inline to work, all the divs that you want to appear on the same line must have that style.  Without it the default is block.

Comment: @SPlatten, I have tried to make both divs inline still the same issue. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @JoykalInfotech, kindly explain to me what is meant by deafult margin in p tag and how to remove that? As in my code i haven't used any margin for p tag. Thanks,

Comment: There is default margin in p tag of 'margin-block-start: 1em; margin-block-end: 1em;'. you can remove it or change it simply by defining it in your css.
Additionally when using bootstrap it applies margin-top: 0; and only left with margin-bottom: 1rem;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use flexbox, you can use `align-items: center`, to horizontally align divs.

```css
.flex-container {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.switch {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 47px;
height: 25px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #ccc;
-webkit-transition: .4s;
transition: .4s;
border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider:before {
position: absolute;
content: "";
height: 17px;
width: 17px;
left: 4px;
bottom: 4px;
background-color: white;
-webkit-transition: .4s;
transition: .4s;
border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked + .slider {
background-color: #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <p id="show_crash_toggle_text" style="font-size:20px;"><b>User</b></p>
  <div>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" onclick = "">
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
<b style="font-size:20px">Search by: </b>
</div>
```

Comment: @ShubhankGupta i changed the snippet, so it uses your initial code

Comment: Really thanks for help, It worked for me and much better orientation than previous one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Code, for horizontal div alignment

```
<style>
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

</style>
```

HTML content

```
<div  class="container" >

  <div  class="block">
    <p id="show_crash_toggle_text" >  <b>User</b>&emsp;</p>
  </div>

  <div  class="block" >
    <p id="show_crash_toggle_text">  <b>User</b>&emsp;</p>
  </div>

  <div class="block" > 
    <p>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" onclick = "show_crash_log()">
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div  class="block" >
    <p> Search by: </p>
   </div>

</div>
```

Try this snippet.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer but using this class .flex_container {
    display:flex;
  align-items: center;
} fixed my problem much better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be avoid using inline css

```css
.switch {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 47px;
height: 25px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #ccc;
-webkit-transition: .4s;
transition: .4s;
border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider:before {
position: absolute;
content: "";
height: 17px;
width: 17px;
left: 4px;
bottom: 4px;
background-color: white;
-webkit-transition: .4s;
transition: .4s;
border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked + .slider {
background-color: #2196F3;
}
.user-switch-wrap{
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;

}
```

```html
<div class="user-switch-wrap">
  <div class="user-txt">
    <p id="show_crash_toggle_text"><b>User</b></p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-switch">
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" onclick = "show_crash_log()">
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="search-by">
    <b>Search by: </b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you using user-switch, user-txt and search-by classes if you haven't declared them in your css?

Comment: there is nothing like declaration for classes in CSS and HTML, its just that these classes are not being used for CSS, and it will not give error, also vice-versa

Comment: I know it will not give any error but i am asking what's the point of using those classes if they don't consist any property? Thanks,

Comment: there is no point using them, she might have thought to use them but later not needed.

Answer (score 0):

i made some changes check this

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p id="show_crash_toggle_text" style="font-size:20px;" <b>User</b>&emsp;</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" onclick = "show_crash_log()">
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <b style="font-size:20px">Search by: </b>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 47px;
    height: 25px;
    margin:0px 10px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This technique worked and toggle and plain text has much better orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Try it dude:

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 47px;
  height: 25px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}


.search-box,
.search-box__toggle{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.search-box__toggle  + * {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-box">
    <div class="search-box__toggle">
        <p id="show_crash_toggle_text" style="font-size:20px;" <b>User</b>&emsp;</p>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" onclick = "show_crash_log()">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <b style="font-size:20px">Search by: </b>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have used your code but initially didn't worked for me. I tried modifying the code little bit and it worked with using class .flex_container {
    display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}
Thanks,

Comment: Nice! Good job.